# "500 Internal Server Error" when combining Scrapy over Splash with an HTTP proxy

Tags: python, scrapy, http-status-code-500, scrapy-splash

I'm trying to crawl a Scrapy spider in a Docker container using both Splash (to render JavaScript) and Tor through Privoxy (to provide anonymity). Here is the `docker-compose.yml` I'm using to this end:

```
version: '3'

services:
  scraper:
    build: ./apk_splash
    # environment:
      # - http_proxy=http://tor-privoxy:8118
    links:
      - tor-privoxy
      - splash

  tor-privoxy:
    image: rdsubhas/tor-privoxy-alpine

  splash:
    image: scrapinghub/splash
```

where the Scraper has the following `Dockerfile`:

```
FROM python:alpine
RUN apk --update add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev gcc musl-dev libgcc openssl-dev curl bash
RUN pip install scrapy scrapy-splash scrapy-fake-useragent
COPY . /scraper
WORKDIR /scraper
CMD ["scrapy", "crawl", "apkmirror"]
```

and the spider I'm trying to crawl is

```
import scrapy
from scrapy_splash import SplashRequest
from apk_splash.items import ApkmirrorItem

class ApkmirrorSpider(scrapy.Spider):
    name = 'apkmirror'
    allowed_domains = ['apkmirror.com']
    start_urls = [
        'http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/cslskku/androbench-storage-benchmark/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-release/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-android-apk-download/',
    ]

    custom_settings = {'USER_AGENT': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_5) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/59.0.3071.115 Safari/537.36'}

    def start_requests(self):
        for url in self.start_urls:
            yield SplashRequest(url=url, callback=self.parse, endpoint='render.html', args={'wait': 0.5})

    def parse(self, response):
        item = ApkmirrorItem()
        item['url'] = response.url
        item['developer'] = response.css('.breadcrumbs').xpath('.//*[re:test(@href, "^/(?:[^/]+/){1}[^/]+/$")]/text()').extract_first()
        item['app'] = response.css('.breadcrumbs').xpath('.//*[re:test(@href, "^/(?:[^/]+/){2}[^/]+/$")]/text()').extract_first()
        item['version'] = response.css('.breadcrumbs').xpath('.//*[re:test(@href, "^/(?:[^/]+/){3}[^/]+/$")]/text()').extract_first()
        yield item
```

where I've added the following to `settings.py`:

```
SPIDER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashDeduplicateArgsMiddleware': 100,
}

DOWNLOADER_MIDDLEWARES = {
    'scrapy_splash.SplashCookiesMiddleware': 723,
    'scrapy_splash.SplashMiddleware': 725,
    'scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpcompression.HttpCompressionMiddleware': 810,
}

SPLASH_URL = 'http://splash:8050/'

DUPEFILTER_CLASS = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareDupeFilter'
HTTPCACHE_STORAGE = 'scrapy_splash.SplashAwareFSCacheStorage'
```

With the `environment` for the `scraper` container commented out, the Scraper more-or-less works. I get logs containing the following:

```
scraper_1      | 2017-07-11 13:57:19 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (200) <GET http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/cslskku/androbench-storage-benchmark/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-release/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-android-apk-download/ via http://splash:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
scraper_1      | 2017-07-11 13:57:19 [scrapy.core.scraper] DEBUG: Scraped from <200 http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/cslskku/androbench-storage-benchmark/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-release/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-android-apk-download/>
scraper_1      | {'app': 'Androbench (Storage Benchmark)',
scraper_1      |  'developer': 'CSL@SKKU',
scraper_1      |  'url': 'http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/cslskku/androbench-storage-benchmark/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-release/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-android-apk-download/',
scraper_1      |  'version': '5.0'}
scraper_1      | 2017-07-11 13:57:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
scraper_1      | 2017-07-11 13:57:19 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
scraper_1      | {'downloader/request_bytes': 1508,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/request_count': 3,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 2,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 1,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/response_bytes': 190320,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/response_count': 3,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/response_status_count/200': 2,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/response_status_count/404': 1,
scraper_1      |  'finish_reason': 'finished',
scraper_1      |  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 11, 13, 57, 19, 488874),
scraper_1      |  'item_scraped_count': 1,
scraper_1      |  'log_count/DEBUG': 5,
scraper_1      |  'log_count/INFO': 7,
scraper_1      |  'memusage/max': 49131520,
scraper_1      |  'memusage/startup': 49131520,
scraper_1      |  'response_received_count': 3,
scraper_1      |  'scheduler/dequeued': 2,
scraper_1      |  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 2,
scraper_1      |  'scheduler/enqueued': 2,
scraper_1      |  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 2,
scraper_1      |  'splash/render.html/request_count': 1,
scraper_1      |  'splash/render.html/response_count/200': 1,
scraper_1      |  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 11, 13, 57, 13, 788850)}
scraper_1      | 2017-07-11 13:57:19 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
apksplashcompose_scraper_1 exited with code 0
```

However, if I comment in the `environment` lines in the `docker-compose.yml`, I get a 500 Internal Server Error:

```
scraper_1      | 2017-07-11 14:05:07 [scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.retry] DEBUG: Gave up retrying <GET http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/cslskku/androbench-storage-benchmark/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-release/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-android-apk-download/ via http://splash:8050/render.html> (failed 3 times): 500 Internal Server Error
scraper_1      | 2017-07-11 14:05:07 [scrapy.core.engine] DEBUG: Crawled (500) <GET http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/cslskku/androbench-storage-benchmark/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-release/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-android-apk-download/ via http://splash:8050/render.html> (referer: None)
scraper_1      | 2017-07-11 14:05:07 [scrapy.spidermiddlewares.httperror] INFO: Ignoring response <500 http://www.apkmirror.com/apk/cslskku/androbench-storage-benchmark/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-release/androbench-storage-benchmark-5-0-android-apk-download/>: HTTP status code is not handled or not allowed
scraper_1      | 2017-07-11 14:05:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Closing spider (finished)
scraper_1      | 2017-07-11 14:05:07 [scrapy.statscollectors] INFO: Dumping Scrapy stats:
scraper_1      | {'downloader/request_bytes': 3898,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/request_count': 7,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/request_method_count/GET': 4,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/request_method_count/POST': 3,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/response_bytes': 6839,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/response_count': 7,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/response_status_count/200': 1,
scraper_1      |  'downloader/response_status_count/500': 6,
scraper_1      |  'finish_reason': 'finished',
scraper_1      |  'finish_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 11, 14, 5, 7, 866713),
scraper_1      |  'httperror/response_ignored_count': 1,
scraper_1      |  'httperror/response_ignored_status_count/500': 1,
scraper_1      |  'log_count/DEBUG': 10,
scraper_1      |  'log_count/INFO': 8,
scraper_1      |  'memusage/max': 49065984,
scraper_1      |  'memusage/startup': 49065984,
scraper_1      |  'response_received_count': 3,
scraper_1      |  'retry/count': 4,
scraper_1      |  'retry/max_reached': 2,
scraper_1      |  'retry/reason_count/500 Internal Server Error': 4,
scraper_1      |  'scheduler/dequeued': 4,
scraper_1      |  'scheduler/dequeued/memory': 4,
scraper_1      |  'scheduler/enqueued': 4,
scraper_1      |  'scheduler/enqueued/memory': 4,
scraper_1      |  'splash/render.html/request_count': 1,
scraper_1      |  'splash/render.html/response_count/500': 3,
scraper_1      |  'start_time': datetime.datetime(2017, 7, 11, 14, 4, 46, 717691)}
scraper_1      | 2017-07-11 14:05:07 [scrapy.core.engine] INFO: Spider closed (finished)
apksplashcompose_scraper_1 exited with code 0
```

In short, when using Splash to render JavaScript, I'm not able to successfully use the [HttpProxyMiddleware](https://doc.scrapy.org/en/latest/topics/downloader-middleware.html#module-scrapy.downloadermiddlewares.httpproxy) in order to also use Tor through Privoxy. Can someone see what is going wrong here?

**Update**

Following Paul's comment, I tried adapting the `splash` service as follows:

```
  splash:
    image: scrapinghub/splash
    volumes:
      - ./splash/proxy-profiles:/etc/splash/proxy-profiles
```

where I've added a 'splash' directory to the main directory like so:

```
.
├── apk_splash
├── docker-compose.yml
└── splash
    └── proxy-profiles
        └── proxy.ini
```

and `proxy.ini` reads

```
[proxy]

host=tor-privoxy
port=8118
```

As I understand it, this should make the proxy be used always (i.e. the `whitelist` defaults to `".*"` and no `blacklist`).

However, if I again `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`, I still get HTTP 500 errors. So the question remains how to solve these?

(Incidentally, this question seems similar to https://github.com/scrapy-plugins/scrapy-splash/issues/117; however, I'm not using Crawlera so I'm not sure how to adapt the answer).

**Update 2**

Following Paul's second comment, I checked that `tor-privoxy` resolves within the container by doing this (while it was still running):

```
~$ docker ps -l
CONTAINER ID        IMAGE                      COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS               NAMES
04909e6ef5cb        apksplashcompose_scraper   "scrapy crawl apkm..."   2 hours ago         Up 8 seconds                            apksplashcompose_scraper_1
~$ docker exec -it $(docker ps -lq) /bin/bash
bash-4.3# python
Python 3.6.1 (default, Jun 19 2017, 23:58:41) 
[GCC 5.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import socket
>>> socket.gethostbyname('tor-privoxy')
'172.22.0.2'
```

As for how I'm running Splash, it's through a linked container, similar to the way described in https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#docker-folder-sharing. I've verified that the `/etc/splash/proxy-profiles/proxy.ini` is present in the container:

```
~$ docker exec -it apksplashcompose_splash_1 /bin/bash
root@b091fbef4c78:/# cd /etc/splash/proxy-profiles
root@b091fbef4c78:/etc/splash/proxy-profiles# ls
proxy.ini
root@b091fbef4c78:/etc/splash/proxy-profiles# cat proxy.ini
[proxy]

host=tor-privoxy
port=8118
```

I will try [Aquarium](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/aquarium), but the question remains why the current setup doesn't work?

Comment: Have you tried using [proxy profiles for Splash](https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/api.html?#proxy-profiles)?

Comment: [paul trmbrth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572383/paul-trmbrth), I tried this (see updated question) but unfortunately I'm still getting 500 errors.

Comment: Might sound stupid, but are you running Splash using `python3 -m splash.server --proxy-profiles-path=...`? Does `tor-privoxy` as host resolve within the Docker image?

Comment: You may also want to have a look at https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/aquarium

Comment: Paul, I'm running Splash in a linked container, but the volume containing the  proxy configuration file is correctly mounted in that container following https://splash.readthedocs.io/en/stable/install.html#docker-folder-sharing (see Update 2 above). I've verified that `tor-privoxy` as host does resolve within the Docker image in accordance with https://docs.docker.com/compose/networking/.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Following the structure of the [Aquarium](https://github.com/TeamHG-Memex/aquarium) project as suggested by [paul trmbrth](https://stackoverflow.com/users/2572383/paul-trmbrth), I found that it is essential to name the .ini file `default.ini`, not `proxy.ini` (otherwise it doesn't get 'picked up' automatically). I managed to get the scraper to work in this way (cf. my self-answer to [How to use Scrapy with both Splash and Tor over Privoxy in Docker Compose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45039850/how-to-use-scrapy-with-both-splash-and-tor-over-privoxy-in-docker-compose)).