# docker: how to retrieve a file (created by scrapy-splash)

Tags: docker, scrapy, docker-compose, scrapy-splash

I use scrapy-splash with docker. 
In Dockerfile I have this line to export the result in a `.jl` .

```
CMD ["scrapy", "crawl", "quotesjs", "-o", "quote.jl"]
```

When I run `docker-compose build` and `docker-compose up`, the log informs me that:

```
scrapy1      | 2017-12-18 00:00:00 [scrapy.extensions.feedexport] INFO: Stored jl feed (10 items) in: quote.jl
```

I don't see any `quote.jl` in my local folder (where the Dockerfile and the scrapy project is), so I guesse it should be in my container. 
I trie to cp the content of the container with this command but without success.

```
docker cp containerID:. ./copy_of_container
```

How can I retrieve the `quote.jl` file.

I am on Windows10 and I use Docker for Windows

---

My dockerfile

```
FROM python:alpine
RUN apk --update add libxml2-dev libxslt-dev libffi-dev gcc musl-dev libgcc openssl-dev curl bash
RUN pip install scrapy scrapy-splash scrapy-fake-useragent
ADD . /scraper
WORKDIR /scraper

CMD ["scrapy", "crawl", "apkmirror", "-o", "apkmirror.jl"]
```

Comment: you can "assign" local folder as folder in docker and then it write in your folder instead folder inside docker but probably you can do only when you create new image (which later runs as container).

Comment: [How to mount host directory in docker container?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/23439126/how-to-mount-host-directory-in-docker-container)

Comment: Thanks furas! On the link provided, it seems that something like  `docker run -v /host/directory:/container/directory -other -options image_name command_to_run` could do what I want but I am not sure how to implement it especially the image_name and command_to_run. I simply create the docker image by doing a `docker-compose build` and then `docker-compose up`. The parameters are in the Dockerfile and  docker-compose.yml as explained here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45105145/7227370.

Comment: as shown in previous link you could use `ADD` in `Dockerfile` to asssign/link your local folder as folder in docker and then it can write directly to your folder.

Comment: as for `command_to_run` - if you run without `command_to_run` then it should run internal `bash` and you may use `ls` to display files in folder. See examples in doc: [docker run](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/run/#parent-command)

Comment: Thanks for all this @furas! I have added my dockerfile. I have replace the `COPY . /scraper` by `ADD . /scraper`. but still I dont' see any `apkmirror.jl` in my local folder